# Почему "кулаки"?

Tags: этимология

Почему зажиточных крестьян во времена коллективизации называли "кулаками"? При чем тут фигура из пальцев?

Comment: Может, потому, что они "держали в кулаке" окружающих? 

Comment: Кулак сильный, крепкий, хозяйство крепкое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут вопрос не совсем корректный. Термин сложился гораздо раньше коллективизации, в дореволюционной России. Потом он неоднократно переосмысливался, но этимологию-то следует искать по исходному значению. А оно относилось к зажиточному крестьянину, использующему наемный труд, преимущественно - батрацкий. Тем самым кулак как бы держал в руке всю общину.
Так что DocentI права.

Answer (score 3):

Это не многозначное слово, а 2 омонима: кулак-рука и кулак-перекупщик.

КУЛАК 1 . Общеслав. Образовалось от той же праславянской основы, что kuliti "сжимать в комок" < "гнуть, сжимать",( кукиш -исходный корень — ку- < *kou-). Эта же основа у слова культя)kul - и рука, и нога - кость конечности. Для понятия  рука было слово пясть. Потом появилось кулак - согнутая пясть.

Кулак 2. Слово возникло в жаргоне офеней, торговцев, разъезжавших с своим товаром по деревням и наживавших на нем, не без жульничества и ростовщичества, большие деньги."Справочный общедоступный энциклопедический словарь" 1901 года расширяет трактовку термина и определяет, что «Кулак человек, наживающий большие барыши, эксплуатируя других»  В данном случае, слово «эксплуатируя» открывает возможность марксистской трактовки термина. Видимо, большевиками этот «мостик» был в дальнейшем использован. От переносного значения разговорного слова «кулак», означающего «скупой», корыстолюбивый человек, или рода занятий (перекупщик, посредник) советская пропаганда целенаправленно работала над созданием значения «классовый враг», «эксплуататор».Даже в позднесоветском Словаре Ожегова 1983 года издания «кулак» определяется как «Богатый крестьянин-собственник, эксплуатирующий батраков, бедняков». Это определение устоялось в словарях с конца 1950-х гг. Один из новейших словарей - Современный толковый словарь русского языка, - под редакцией. С.А.Кузнецова, трактует термин «кулак» как «Богатый крестьянин-собственник, использующий труд батраков». То есть словари закрепили значение идеологемы, опираясь на события, которые суть пропагандистская кампания. Перед партией большевиков стояла задача разжигание вражды и на роль врага, взамен ушедшего класса «помещика» требовался новый враг. Он был искусственно вычленен и классово обозначен «кулаком».

В советских  словарях, «мироед» и «кулак» будут использоваться как синонимы, находящиеся в одном ряду с понятиями «эксплуататор» и «классовый враг». Так что к кулаку-руке это слово никак не относится. Гоголь же в "Мёртвых душах", каламбурно сливши эти два слова, заставляет Чичикова изречь целый ряд афоризмов: ”Нет, кто уж кулак, тому не разогнуться в ладонь! А разогни кулаку один или два пальца, выйдет еще хуже“» (Виноградов. О языке худож. лит., с. 141—143).

Comment: >То есть словари закрепили значение идеологемы, опираясь на события, которые суть пропагандистская кампания  

Не вижу "идеологеммы". Максимум, что можно утверждать, прияняв свё сказанное, это сужение значения от "эксплуататора вообще" до эксплуататора-крестьянина. Ничем более исходное и "пропагандистское" значение не различается. Да и фиксируется оно в текстах, например, Герцена и Писемского... (см. нацкорпус).    

Хотя и по фактам тут есть вопросы. Про язык офеней, нпример. В современной фене, вобравшей в себя едва ли не весь их "словарный запас" такого значения не фиксируется.

Comment: Честно говоря, удивлена, что словари дают эти слова как омонимы. Но, кстати,  у ДАля и у Ушакова это значения одного слова.

Comment: Ну это, имхо, вопрос вкуса. Происхождение одного значения от другого никто не оспаривает, а там хоть омонимами назови, хоть горшком...

Comment: Вопрос в том, что как раз оспариваю вслед за акад. Соболевским, кот. пишет:«древнерусский язык вместо современного кулак, употребляет пясть; по-видимому, некогда кулак имело другое значение и лишь с течением времени получило значение современное». Он находит возможным сближать слово кулак либо с куль, кулек, либо с кѫтати (кутать). По-видимому, кулак в древнерусском языке обозначал что-то вроде мешка, куля, обвертки. И далее : "С старшим значением слова кулак связано другое современное его значение: `крестьянин-торговец в деревне, скупщик". А кулак-рука от kuliti "сжимать в комок".

Comment: Вы считаете, что «эксплуататор» и «классовый враг» не идеологемы? А значение не сужалось, а именно менялось в сторону идеологии:торговец мелким товаром - скупой/корыстолюбивый/жулик - "наживающий большие барыши обманом " - эксплуататор - «классовый враг».

Comment: А почему же тогда кулаков находили только в деревне? В городе жуликоватых торговцев тоже хватало.

Comment: Я считаю: 
1) что "классовый враг" идеологизм, но он никак не связан со значением слова "кулак".  
2) "эксплуататор" - весбма слабый идеологизм, в значении, которое можно притянуть к "кулаку", он идеологизмам не является.

Но вы-то говорите о "значении идеологемы" слова *кулак*, каковой она точно не является. Современное словарное значение лишь немного сужает исходное. Никакой идеологии.

>Вопрос в том, что как раз оспариваю вслед за акад  

Вы серьёзно полагаете, что "кулак"(= зачиточный крестьянин) мог произойте напрямую от куля и проч. а не от от кулака - сжатой ладони? Не верю. Обоснуйте.

Comment: @Людмила, "приз" не за сам ответ и не за "идеологию", она сомнительна, да и наплевать мне на неё. А вот мысль о "параллельной" этимологии двух значений кулака - это да.  
@Ларf, если один кулак не от другого произошел, то это - омонимы...

//=====  
  
>А почему же тогда кулаков находили только в деревне? В городе жуликоватых торговцев тоже хватало.  
     
Их тоже какое-то время называли кулаками. Не столько даже торговцев, сколько вообще крепких хохйственников, подминающих под себя окружающих. В нацорпусе есть примеры. если будет нужда - завтра найду. Сейчас уже пора прощаться, сорри.

Answer (score 0):

Я слышал, что "кулак" называли зажиточного крестьянина спавшего на кулаке, что бы утром не проспать! И вообще в первую очередь хозяин, а не лентяй (пьяница) которых тоже хватало!

Answer (score 0):

Я по- своему сформировала ответ:кулак- на башкирском, значит, кул- рука,ак- белая.белая рука. на русском-сразу понятно-кулак- это свой, сплоченный, сомкнутый. Родственники мужа были сосланы в Сибирь.Это были очень трудолюбивые хорошие люди в зависть некоторым.самых отчаянных расстрелили.проще было отнимать у них все, чем убивать.

Answer (score 0):

Этимология слова КУЛАК ближе всего образовалось от тюркского КУЛ (рука), где вторая часть слова АК означает белая, то есть это слово можно понять как БЕЛОРУЧКА, либо как РУКА БЕЗ ОРУЖИЯ. И считаю именно отсюда появилось название состязаний кулачных боёв. Раньше на Руси правую руку называли десницей, левую шуйцей, но кулачные бои уже существовали.

Answer (score -1):

Согласен, с мнением , что" кулак"-потому,что это  люди которые работали очень много и спали мало, и спали подложив кулак под голову. А потом пришла банда многочисленная тех людей , которые не хотели работать, и стали раскулачивать( отбирать ) у людей их честнозаработанные  деньги, вещи и жильё. Короче- всё. Одним словом " кулаки" - это те люди, которые хотели заработать и работать. А сейчас мы с вами( большинством, средним и ниже среднего классом)- кулаки. А "банда"так дальше нас и раскулачивает.